# Play Framework - Respond with JSON after uploading a file (multipartFormData)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am using this code to upload an image on server , that i get from this link [play upload](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaFileUpload)

```scala
 def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body
      .file("picture")
      .map { picture =>
        val dataParts = request.body.dataParts;

        val filename = Paths.get(picture.filename).getFileName
        val fileSize = picture.fileSize
        val contentType = picture.contentType

         val picturePaths =
           picture.ref.copyTo(
             Paths.get(
               s"/opt/docker/images/$filename"
             ),
             replace = true
           )
        if (dataParts.get("firstPoint") == None) {
          val pointlocation = new Point_LocationModel(
            dataParts.get("step").get(0),
            dataParts.get("backgroundTargetName").get(0),
            dataParts.get("x").get(0),
            dataParts.get("y").get(0),
            dataParts.get("z").get(0),
            dataParts.get("rotation").get(0),
            dataParts.get("note").get(0),
            dataParts.get("tag").get(0),
            dataParts.get("work_session_id").get(0),
            (picturePaths).toString
          )
          point_LocationRepository.create(pointlocation).map { data =>
            Created(Json.toJson(data._2))
          }
        } else {
          val jValuefirstPoint =
            Json.parse(dataParts.get("firstPoint").get(0)).as[PointModel]
          val jValuesecondPoint =
            Json.parse(dataParts.get("secondPoint").get(0)).as[PointModel]

          val pointlocation = new Point_LocationModel(
            dataParts.get("step").get(0),
            dataParts.get("backgroundTargetName").get(0),
            Some(jValuefirstPoint),
            Some(jValuesecondPoint),
            dataParts.get("rotation").get(0),
            dataParts.get("note").get(0),
            dataParts.get("tag").get(0),
            dataParts.get("work_session_id").get(0),
            (picturePaths).toString
          )
          point_LocationRepository.create(pointlocation).map { data =>
            logger.info(s"repoResponse:  ${data}");
            Created(Json.toJson(data._2))
          }
        }
        Ok(s"picturePaths ${picturePaths}")

      }
      .getOrElse(Ok("Invalid Format"))
  }
```

This code works very well, but on the response I want to get the response from the repository. How can i await for the response of the repository to return this?

Can you give me any idea how can i do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what did you try? What's blocking you? You already have both informations (name and size), it's just a matter of sending it in the response..

Comment: Hello, i have change the question for my specific code that i have implement. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we simplify your code to the essential bits, you have:

```scala
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body
      .file("picture")
      .map { picture =>
        if (someConditionA) {
          someBusinessLogicA().map { data =>
            Created(Json.toJson(data._2))
          }
        } else {
          someBusinessLogicB().map { data =>
            Created(Json.toJson(data._2))
          }
        }
        Ok(s"picturePaths ${picturePaths}")
      }
      .getOrElse(Ok("Invalid Format"))
}
```

There are 2 problems:

- the return of your `if/else` is swallowed by the `Ok(s"picturePaths ${picturePaths}")`
- assuming your business logic returns `Future[_]` you need to "propagate" the Future everywhere

Something like this should work:

```scala
def upload = Action.async(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body
      .file("picture")
      .map { picture =>
        if (someConditionA) {
          someBusinessLogicA().map { data =>
            Created(Json.toJson(data._2))
          }
        } else {
          someBusinessLogicB().map { data =>
            Created(Json.toJson(data._2))
          }
        }
      }
      .getOrElse(Future.successful(Ok("Invalid Format")))
}
```

*Notice the `Action.async` and the `Future` in the `getOrElse`.*